# How can i poll GPIO with 100ms timeout in stm32?

Tags: stm32, gpio, polling, hal

I need to poll `GPIO` input pin during 100ms and return error if there is no respond at 100ms. I configured `TIM2` on `CubeIDE` but I can not write the condition and I can not decide to use while or if statement. Could you help me?

Comment: You may do it either on bare metal or with help of RTOS (e.g. Zephyr).

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to use the tick timer with the `SysTick_Handler` function. the interval is configurable but most of the time this function calls each 1ms. So you can use a global counter within it and detect the timeout. remember that you should reset the counter if the desired event happened.

```
uint32_t cntr = 0;                              

void SysTick_Handler(void)  {                               
   cntr++;
   if(cntr > 100){
      // timeout happened hear
      cntr=0;
   }                                       
}
```